# Post-quantum security of multiple-encryption with CTR mode of operation while keeping the IVs secret

Tags: block-cipher, post-quantum-cryptography, initialization-vector, ctr, meet-in-the-middle-attack

I received an [answer in one of my questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98436/89581) saying that multiple-encryption with CTR mode of operation is vulnerable to a sort of meet-in-the-middle attack if the IVs are public. The same user said that [keeping the IVs secret such attack not applies](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/98433/is-multiple-encryption-using-a-block-cipher-mode-of-operation-that-use-only-encr/98436#comment212991_98436) and that the cost of breaking a double-encryption with brute-force for example is multiplied by 2*[IV lenght].

Does encrypting two times with CTR mode while keeping the IVs secret suffer from some kind of attack in the quantum model such as Grover's algorithm?

Comment: Yet if the IVs are secret, how would you decrypt?

Comment: @PaulUszak I mean, obviously, secret from the others,