# Can the encryption with CTR mode be replaced by a publicly known unkeyed permutation when doing multiple encryption and keeping the IV secret?

Tags: keys, initialization-vector, modes-of-operation, ctr

A user of this forum [answered in one of my questions and said](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98436/89581) that if the IV is kept secret in multiple encryption with CTR mode, the cost of breaking the scheme is $${2^{2 l_{key}}} 2 \cdot {2^{l_{iv}}}$$

Can the encryption operation in multiple-encryption with CTR mode be replaced by a non-cryptographic operation assuming the IV is kept secret?

I'm questioning this because I took a look in the [Even–Mansour scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor) and could see that the encryption operation can be replaced by a publicly known unkeyed permutation.

Comment: Two remarks: Even-Mansour doesn't use an IV, so it is not secure as a normal cipher: identical plaintext blocks will end up as identical ciphertext unless the key is updated. Furthermore, the XOR with a key is basically working as a one time pad. Without a key, CTR mode is not even a cipher, as the block cipher is the only location where the key is actually used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> by a publicly known *permutation*...

No, that'd be a bad idea.  Consider if the attacker received the two-block message:

$$M_0 \oplus \text{Perm}( IV ), M_1 \oplus \text{Perm}( IV+1 )$$

and also happened to know (or guess) $M_0$ (partial known plaintext).  Then, he could recover $\text{Perm}(IV)$, and then invert the permutation to recover $IV$

Even-Mansour avoids this issue by adding an xor of secret data after the permutation...

Comment: True in the cases likely under consideration, but there are examples of permutations that are not easy to invert. e.g. RSA permutes residues mod $N$ and modular exponentiation mod $p$ permutes 1,…, $p-1$